If a union semilattice and intersection semilattice are isomorphic, can the structures be combined into something similar to a distributive lattice?
Starting with the power set of the symmetric group $\mathcal{P}(S_n)$, we can define a semilattice of subsets $\Gamma$ whose meet operation is given by set intersection using a closure operator $cl: \mathcal{P}(S_n) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(S_n)$. Using two-line notation for the permutations, we can represent each of them as a perfect matching in an $(n, n)$-bipartite graph. For each subset $S \subseteq S_n$, we define $cl(S)$ to be the set of all perfect matchings in the bipartite graph formed from the union of $S$.
For each subset $S \subseteq S_n$, we have $S \subseteq cl(S)$ and $cl(cl(S)) = cl(S)$, so it is extensive and idempotent. Also, for each $T$ such that $S \subseteq T$, we have $cl(S) \subseteq cl(T)$, so it is monotonic/increasing. Therefore, we satisfy the axioms for a closure operator and $\Gamma$ forms a Moore family, a family of sets closed under intersection.
We can define a bijection to another semilattice $\Lambda$ by taking each closed set of perfect matchings in $\Gamma$ to the set of edges of the associated bipartite graph (ie the biadjacency matrix of the graph). For each $M \in \Lambda$, every edge in $M$ is contained in a perfect matching ie perfectly-matchable. For any $M, N \in \Lambda$, each edge in $M \cup N$ maintains this property since we are not deleting any of the edges, so $M \cup N \in \Lambda$. Therefore, $\Lambda$ is a family of sets closed under union. (We can represent $\Lambda$ as the face lattice of the Birkhoff polytope $B_n$)
The bijection between the two semilattices is denoted $\phi: \Gamma \leftrightarrow \Lambda$.
A join operation can be defined for $\Gamma$ and a meet operation for $\Lambda$, turning them both into lattices, though these can’t be given by union and intersection, respectively. The union of two closed sets in $\Gamma$ may not contain all of the perfect matchings which cover the associated biadjacency matrix and the intersection of two edge-sets in $\Lambda$ may contain edges which are not perfectly-matchable. However, using a transport of structure argument, we can use the bijection $\phi$ to pull the operations from one lattice into the other.
I haven’t proven the homomorphism here, but it’s not too difficult. The closed union of two sets of perfect matchings is the set of perfect matchings that can be formed from the union of their edge-sets. The filtered intersection of two perfectly-matchable edge-sets is the edge-set of the shared perfect matchings.
For each $S, T \in \Gamma$, we have $\phi(S \vee T) = \phi(S) \cup \phi(T) \Leftrightarrow S \vee T = \phi^{-1}(\phi(S) \cup \phi(T))$.
For each $M, N \in \Lambda$, we have $\phi^{-1}(M \wedge N) = \phi^{-1}(M) \cap \phi^{-1}(N) \Leftrightarrow M \wedge N = \phi(\phi^{-1}(M) \cap \phi^{-1}(N))$.
I’ve been trying to show that there are “quasi-distributive” laws which these lattices satisfy:
$U \cap \phi^{-1}(\phi(S) \cup \phi(T)) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(U \cap S) \cup \phi(U \cap T))$*
$O \cup \phi(\phi^{-1}(M) \cap \phi^{-1}(N)) = \phi(\phi^{-1}(O \cup M) \cap \phi^{-1}(O \cup N))$*
I’m just a bit stumped and don’t know if I’m getting tripped up by the confusing notation or if I’m missing a simple counter example. Also, I haven’t seen anywhere that the face lattice of the Birkhoff polytope is distributive, just Eulerian. I’ve found several families of objects which lead to this same construction, but what I’ve outlined here is the simplest of them.
*Edit: Made some changes to terminology and simplified the statement of the “quasi-distributive” laws of intersection over closed union / union over filtered intersection which I now know is false
$U \cap (S \vee T) = (U \cap S) \vee (U \cap T)$
$O \cup (M \wedge N) = (O \cup M) \wedge (O \cup N)$

Looks like I missed an incredibly simple counter example… Changing the notation really helped.
$\{2143\} \cap (\{1243\} \cup_{\phi} \{2134\}) = \{2143\} \cap \{1234, 1243, 2134, 2143\} = \{2134\}$
$(\{2143\} \cap \{1243\}) \cup_{\phi} (\{2143\} \cap \{2134\}) = \emptyset \cup_{\phi} \emptyset = \emptyset$
